How Can I delete Comet Executor.exe from AppData\Romaing\Comet Executor?
My friend's 11yrs old son visited at home with family and let him use my desktop. This generation kids are genius with computer, and installed cloud based game program called Comet Executor. It hidden at my computer. I could not able to see from Control Panel \Program \uninstalled program. I could not able to search that program named Comet Executor nor Comet Executor.exe file at my system at my computer skill. However, when I opened it runs itself and pop up on my screen and its shortcut open at my toolbar (bottom of my screen). How can I delete that cloud base Comet Executor.exe file and stop running or cleaned all its related programs or files?
Thank you.
I could not able to see from Control Panel \Program \uninstalled program. I could not able to search that program named Comet Executor nor Comet Executor.exe file at my system at my computer skill.

Comet and pretty much all other executors dont actually install themselves as programs/applications like other huge mega apps where the system puts them in the control panel. they actually just reside in a simple exe. so you simply have to delete the exe wherever your friend's son installed it to.
